# Sort/optimize values array to enable 16-bit indices in sub-arrays

Tags: sorting, optimization, heuristics

I have many small arrays that combined hold millions items (many of them duplicates). To save space I've moved all items to one master array without duplicates. Original arrays now hold indices to values in master array.

Problem is that I would like to use 16-bit indices instead of 32-bit indices to save additional space. Each array holds from few hundred to few thousand items (all are comfortably below 65535 items). Each array with 16-bit indices has defined offset value, so 32-bit index is calculated as `offset + 16bitIndex`.

Is there any algorithm that would sort master array in a way that arrays with offset & 16-bit indices could be used? Not all arrays need to be 16-bit, just as much as possible. Duplicates in master array are also possible. (Adding few duplicates, to convert additional array to 16-bit still results in less space used.)

PS: I can't think of good, descriptive title for this. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand this correctly:

Your original data is a whole bunch of arrays (I'm using strings to illustrate the concept, but the arrays could contain items of any type):

```
array1 = [Joe, Bob, Sam, Cindy]
array2 = [Susie, Pamela, Cindy, Joe]
array3 = [Cindy, Bob, Susie, Sam]
```

Each array has fewer than 65,536 items, and together they hold millions of items, with many duplicates.

So you create a master array that contains unique items:

```
master = [Joe, Bob, Sam, Cindy, Susie, Pamela]
```

And you re-coded your arrays to contain indexes that refer to the items in the master array:

```
newArray1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
newArray2 = [4, 5, 3, 0]
newArray3 = [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Because the `master` array contains millions of items, the indexes in the new arrays have to be 32 bit.

This is a win if the memory saved by removing duplicate strings is larger than the memory used by the 32-bit indexes in the new arrays. To get the item that was previously stored at `array1[1]`, you write:

```
item = master[newArray1[1]]
```

You've noticed that you can save space in some arrays by making the values 16-bit offsets from a base value. If the indexes in `newArray1` all fell within a range of 65,536 or fewer values, then you can code the indexes as 16 bits, and supply a base. So if `newArray1` contained 5,000 indexes that all fall within the range of [8,749, 47,568], then `base` would be 8,749, and the index 8,749 would become 0, and 47,568 would be 38,819. Your expression to reference the master array is `item = master[base+newArray1[1]]`

### Low-hanging fruit

The first thing I'd do is examine the master list for clusters. For example, there could be a group of 100 arrays that together use 25,000 items from the master list. Those items aren't used by any other arrays, and those arrays use only those 25,000 items. Quite possibly, there are many such clusters. We then place the individual cluster items together in the master array. All of the index lists that use those clusters can be coded with the base+offset method.

Finding the clusters isn't just difficult, just involved. The general idea:

Build an inverted index: a mapping of master item to index array. Imagine you have three index arrays:

```
array1: [joe, bob, cindy, susie]
array2: [cindy, pamela, sam]
array3: [bill, peter, mike, cordelia]
```

Your inverted index, then, is:

```
joe: [array1]
bob: [array1]
cindy: [array1, array2]
susie: [array1]
pamela: [array2]
sam: [array2]
bill: [array3]
peter: [array3]
mike: [array3]
cordelia: [array3]
```

To find the clusters, use [spreading activation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreading_activation). You start with `array1`, and add all of the master items it contains into a queue. Then, for each item in the queue, look up that item and add all of the items from the arrays associated with that item to the cluster. And add them to the queue if they aren't already there. In code:

```
queue = [joe, bob, cindy, susie]  // items from array1
cluster = [joe, bob, cindy, susie]
cluster_lists = []

while queue has items
    item = queue.dequeue
    list_of_arrays = inverted_index[item]
    for each index_array in list_of_arrays
        if cluster_list does not contain array
            add array to cluster list
            for each array_item in index_array
                if cluster does not contain array_item
                    add array_item to cluster
                    add array_item to queue
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When that loop has ended, you will have identified a cluster. That cluster is all of the lists that contain 'joe', and any other item that is in a list that contains 'joe', and recursively all the way down.

Now, if the `cluster` contains fewer than 65,536 items, you can put all of those items sequentially in the master list, code all of the arrays in `cluster_lists` to use your base+offset indexing scheme.

Continue to create clusters from the remaining items, until every item is in a cluster.

I think the worst case running time is something like O(n * m * a), where n is the number of items in the master list, m is the number of index lists, and a is the average length of the index lists. This will take a bit of time with millions of items, thousands of index lists, and an average of a few thousand items per list. You'll want to try it out on some progressively larger subsets, once you get it working.

### Other thoughts

If a cluster is larger than 65,536 items, You can use your current technique to find arrays in that cluster. Also, as you mentioned, there might be a way to add duplicates to a larger cluster, which could break it into two or more, smaller, clusters. I'll have to give some thought to that.

It's also possible to rearrange items in a large cluster so that a larger number of arrays can be coded as base+offset. I have the inkling of an idea for that, but can't pin it down yet.

Comment: Your explanation is perfect till the `item = master[newArray1[1]]`. Each newArray also has 32-bit offset associated with it. To get the item I write `item = master[offset1 + newArray1[1]]`.

Offset is calculated like this. After newArray1 with 32-bit indices is build, I search for minimum and maximum index values inside newArray1. If difference between min & max index values is less than 65,535, newArray1 can be converted to array with 16-bit indices. To do so first offset1 is set to minimum value. Then all indices are subtracted by offset1 `newArray1Small[0..n] = newArray1[0..n] - offset1`

Comment: Small percent of arrays can already be converted to 16 bit (just by chance, without any special ordering when adding items to master array). I am searching if there is a way to re-order items in master array and / or add few strategically placed duplicates to convert higher percentage of arrays to 16 bit?

Comment: I see. We know, for example, that the first array can have 16 bit offsets because all of its items are by definition within the first 65,536 positions. You're looking for an optimum (or at least better) order. Let me give that a bit more thought. On the face of it, it looks like an NP problem, but perhaps there are some heuristics we can use.

Comment: Slow performance is not a big problem, as data is going to be pre-processed like this only on my computer.

Comment: @zigzag: See my update, with a first-pass solution using clustering.

Comment: Wow thank you for that comprehensive explanation!
I'll try to implement this and report back how it goes...

Comment: I finnaly implemented this algorithm. 30 clusters are created, but sadly only ~2000 items are in small clusters. Two huge clusters hold 99.9% of items. Of these two one contains 3.4 mio items and the other one 96 thousand. Interesting thing is that during coding when I was working with only partial data, more clusters were found.

Comment: I was thinking how to find candidates to duplicate, to split big cluster. That would be the smallest array (or smallest cluster) inside the big cluster that splits it into two parts, if items that are shared between these two parts of the big cluster are duplicated. I tried two ideas of my own, but ended writing recursive algorithm that never completed both times.

Comment: @zigzag: When I was thinking about this over the weekend, I feared that you might end up with a supercluster or two. Your data is more random than I had hoped. Your data is like a game of "Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon." Unfortunate. You could try putting the supercluster items together in the same relative order they were in originally.

Comment: @zigzag: I have some ideas on how to split your super clusters, but they're a little too long for comments. If you'd like to email me (jim AT mischel DOT com), I'd be happy to discuss them with you. Mention Stackoverflow in the subject line.